# Value in Select using ng-options is not populating

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

This is a basic query but for some reason failing and need help.

`<select>` is not populating the value when try to edit an entity. It should show value returned from db for this property but it does not, I have `ng-model` in place also. I believe it should show Donor value but its showing blank. Also tried with `ng-model = userDTO.memberType.description`.

Where I am going wrong with this ?

```
<select     
    name="memberType"
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="userDTO.memberType"
    ng-options="mt.description for mt in mtList">                           
</select>
```

Controller Code:

```
userService.findUserWithContactAndAddress($stateParams.user).then(
    function(response) {                        
        $scope.userDTO = response;      
        console.log("<<FullUserDetails>>:", response);
});
```

Service Response

```
<<FullUserDetails>>: 
  {id: 77, 
   donorType: {
     id: 2,
     desc: "Organization"
   } 
   memberType: {
     id: 4, 
     description: "Donor",
     $$hashKey: "object:45"
   }, 
   $$hashKey: "object:44"
 }
```

---

Just to clarify, I do get full list of values as drop down from db but the selected value for a specific user at the time of editUser function does not populate but instead MemberType is coming as blank. Hope its clear.

---

$scope.mtList returns

```
MemberTypes : 
0: {id: 2, description: "CMA Member", $$hashKey: "object:96"}
1: {id: 4, description: "Donor", $$hashKey: "object:97"}
2: {id: 3, description: "Employee", $$hashKey: "object:98"}
3: {id: 6, description: "Other", $$hashKey: "object:99"}
4: {id: 1, description: "Trustee", $$hashKey: "object:100"}
5: {id: 5, description: "Volunteer", $$hashKey: "object:101"}
length: 6
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: What are the contents of `$scope.mtList`?

Comment: I suggest you add new information as comments or edits in your question. Not as new answers.

Comment: There is something wrong with the description of `$scope.mtList`. The `__proto__` should show `Array(6)`. The `<<FullUserDetails>>` has a missing comma. These values can't be trusted.

Comment: Can you create a [PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) which reproduces the problem?

Comment: it works with  ... ng-options="mt as mt.description for mt in mtList track by mt.id"

Answer (score 0):

Use the `select as` form of the select expression:

```
<select     
    name="memberType"
    class="form-control"
    ng-model="userDTO.memberType"
    ̶n̶g̶-̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶=̶"̶m̶t̶.̶d̶e̶s̶c̶r̶i̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶m̶t̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶m̶t̶L̶i̶s̶t̶"̶
    ng-options="mt as mt.description for mt in mtList">                           
</select>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS ng-options API Reference - `select as`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-)

Comment: Thanks I have tried this but does not work, still blank when go on edit page.